# Is it possible to create multiple forms for a single SharePoint list? (SP Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, view, powerapp

I have a single SharePoint list which has 4 Views.

Each view has different fields which are displayed/ hidden.

I would like to create 4 forms (one for each view) which only shows the fields relevant to each specific view.

Is this possible? Maybe in PowerApps?

Comment: You cannot create multiple forms just by customizing the SharePoint List form. However, you can create a standalone PowerApps and design the forms as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

PowerApps is your Way to go!
Otherwise you could make 4 different quick edit views.

Answer (score 0):

How to create tabs in PowerApps in SharePoint Online List Form for your reference:

https://www.sharepointsky.com/powerapps-create-tabs/